# How to discover the IP address of a connected device?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

A simple question to ask, but not so simple to answer - I have a managed switch with a management port and a serial port. The serial port seems not to work, and the mgmt port has an unknown IP address (not the factory default one, it seems). I connect to it directly with a cat-5 cable from my laptop, setup the wired network specially and try to reach the mgmt port.

As far as I can see, it should in principle be possible to use arp-scan, like:

```
# arp-scan -I eth0 0.0.0.0/0
```

or something along those lines, but it will take a long time. Isn't there a way to get a response - something like "who's there"? After all, there is only one address at the other end.

Comment: Sometimes just running `tcpdump` on your interface is sufficient -- most devices emit some sort traffic when they start up.

Comment: i often resort to wireshark and watch it for ~30 seconds for an ip address to pop out in its scrolling output; granted this only works on a quiet network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed switches typically respond to the Link Layer Discovery Protocol (LLDP). You didn't specify which operating system you are running, but on Arch Linux I was able to install the lldpd package, start the lldpd daemon (`sudo systemctl enable lldpd --now`), and use the `lldpcli` client program to find a HP 1810 switch on the network. Use the command `lldpcli show neighbors` and it will show the system name, system description, and management IP of your switch (provided it supports LLDP, and it has not been disabled on the switch.)

Comment: This did indeed solve my problem! Thanks a lot!